# Choosing a good series for the comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm given the series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^4-n-3}$$

I know it converges, however I'm meant to show that by the comparison test. What would be a good choice here? $\frac{1}{k^2}$ and $\frac{1}{k}$ don't work here, obviously.

Comment: It's enough to show that $\frac{n^2}{n^4-n-3}<\frac\alpha{n^2}$ for all sufficiently large $n$, so all you have to do is figure out an acceptable $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

For $ n\ge 3$, we have

$$n\le \frac{n^4}{3}$$
and

$$3\le \frac{n^4}{3}$$

thus

$$n^4-n-3\ge \frac{n^4}{3}$$

and

$$0\le \frac{n^2}{n^4-n-3}\le \frac{3}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges and since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{n^2}{n^4-n-3}}{\dfrac1{n^2}}=1,$$your series converges.

Comment: Excuse me. I meant the "ratio comparison test", often confused with the ratio test (as this is often left as an exercise):
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=c\neq 0$$
This is for sequences that are almost-multiple(this is the only term I found for it). Then convergence of one of the corresponding series gives us convergence of the other.

Comment: @Algebrageek Yes, that it what I have used.